# Add custom column with customer total spent on WooCommerce admin orders list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

We have a lot of returning customers so I'm trying to display user lifetime value (LTV - SUM of all past orders) on WooCommerce admin orders list to quickly identifiy best users.

But I don't even know if that is possible. I have a custom column to see if it's returning buyers or not, but don't have idea where to start for LTV.

My code for marking returned buyers:

```php
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_columns', 
'shalior_wc_set_custom_edit_post_columns',99,1 );
function shalior_wc_set_custom_edit_post_columns($columns) {
    $columns['is-returning'] = __( 'Is returning?', 'your_text_domain' );
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'shalior_wc_is_returning', 99, 2 );
function shalior_wc_is_returning( $column, $post_id ) {
switch ( $column ) {

    case 'is-returning':
        $order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
        $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
        $orders_count = wc_get_customer_order_count( $user_id );
        echo $orders_count > 1 ? '<span style="color: #040404; background: #9ae288; 
  padding: 3px; padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Yes</span>' : "No" ;
        break;
}
} 

add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
    echo '<style>
    td.is-returning.column-is-returning {
    text-align: center;
}
th#is-returning {
    text-align: center;
}
th.manage-column.column-is-returning {
    text-align: center;
}
td.order_coupons.column-order_coupons {
    text-align: center;
}
th#order_coupons {
    text-align: center;
}
th.manage-column.column-order_coupons {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [get_total_spent()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/get_total_spent/) function,  which return how much money a customer has spent

So you get:

```php
/**
 * Add column
 */
function filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['total-spent'] = __( 'LTV', 'woocommerce' );
    
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Populate column
 */
function filter_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Compare
    if ( $column == 'total-spent' ) {
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

        // Is a WC_Order
        if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
            // Get user id
            $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
            
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty ( $user_id ) ) {
                // Get customer
                $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
                
                // Output
                echo $customer->get_total_spent();
            } else {
                // Output
                echo __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'filter_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 10, 2 );
```